# Changing marker and line colours on an asp.net chart using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am displaying Sales on an Area Chart and the sales are for the past 12 months. So the X Axis Series Label is the Months and the Y Axis Series Label is the Sales.

I am wondering if it is possible to mark a change in the markers from a certain date. I have provided an example below. So these are two lines being plotted for different types of sales. If management for the company changed in October 2014, i want the lines and markers to change colour until the end of the chart (Jun 2015).

[image: Chart example]

I need to be able to change this from the code behind. What is my best way of going about this?

Comment: @jstreet i have answered the question myself. See below.

Comment: @jstreet i have edited my answer to include a chart example. Hope this helps. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a for loop to solve this problem.

```
//  If company is selected and is participating
//  Plot the markers as crosses when SP started providing the traffic source
if (clientCompanyParticipating && startDate != DateTime.MinValue)
{
 int monthDifference = 0;

 //  If the Service StartDate is greater than the first date plotted on the chart
 if (startDate > _lastTwelveMonthsStart)
 {
  monthDifference = ((startDate.Year - _lastTwelveMonthsStart.Year) * 12) + startDate.Month - _lastTwelveMonthsStart.Month;
 }

 //  Foreach point specified (i) make the plot marker a cross
 for (int i = monthDifference; i <= 12; i++)
 {
  chtSourceSalesvOverallSalesBreakdown.Series[0].Points[i].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Cross;
  chtSourceSalesvOverallSalesBreakdown.Series[0].Points[i].MarkerSize = 13;

  chtSourceSalesvOverallSalesBreakdown.Series[1].Points[i].MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Cross;
  chtSourceSalesvOverallSalesBreakdown.Series[1].Points[i].MarkerSize = 13;
  }
 }
```

Here is how my chart has turned out with being able to change plotting from a certain date onward. I will note i decided against a colour change and went for a marker style change instead. The change in this example takes place in Oct 2014 onward.
[image]